# VM revert on Multiplication

Tags: solidity

This method is reverting for me at the first line, I'm sending sufficient value, price is uint and set to 20 and the contract has a sufficient amount of tokens to send

```
function buyToken(address _tokenContract) public payable{
      uint amountToPay = msg.value*price;
      IERC20 tokenContract = IERC20(_tokenContract);
      tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, amountToPay);
    }
```

Comment: What solidity version are you using? What are the values for price and msg.value?